# access dynamically added element on parent window

Tags: javascript

I need to get information from parent window on a new window. For that I use--

```
$("#mains").html($(window.opener.document).find(".dqe").html());
```

Or

```
    $("#mains").html($(".dqe", window.opener.document).html());
```

It works good. But if I have some elements that are dynamically added on the parent window, the new window doesn't get that part.

Can anyone please help??

Comment: Please share a runnable code

Answer (score 0):

Your function only loads the data from the parent window when it is called.

To keep the document in sync you would either need to poll for new data on the other window (run your code again at an interval). You could also send a message to the new window when changes occur using `postMessage()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Off course these are just some options, bottom line is the second window won't know when it should update unless you tell it when to.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your message. But my problem is something different. The problem is not that I may get new elements on the parent window (page A) after opening new one (page B). The problem is that, after opening page A, I make changes to it and add some new rows using jquery. and then I open page B from page A and try to get all the information from A. But I get only those rows that I get while loading page A and miss the newly added rows. I hope, you understood.

Comment: Could you share some runnable code, like in a CodePen, I guess I'm missing some context to answer your problem